# Automatic Event Wiring in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, event-handling, global-asax

I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically stub in the Global.asax's event handlers? Thus far, I've not been able to find any examples of how to do this. Seems I have to just find the list of delegate names available to me and type them in manually.

Intellisense doesn't seem to lend any useful info on the subject either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ASP.Net runtime uses reflection to dynamically look for methods with names like "Application_Start", "Session_Start" etc. and then binds them to the corresponding events on the HttpApplication class. You can effectively bind to any of the HttpApplication events simply by including a method in Global.asax.cs whose name is "Application_" followed by the name of the event. For example, to utilize the EndRequest event, add this to your Global.asax.cs file:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
```

See this [Blog Entry](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jun/18/How-do-ASPNET-Application-Events-Work) from Rick Strahl for a bunch of helpful information on how this is done.

Comment: Honestly all my OOPS concepts had gone for a toss when I saw those methods getting called without override keyword. Reflection is the ghost rider here :-). Thanks for this great enlightenment. Simply ultra-cool. But I was wondering people generally say that inspecting types through reflection is slow and can be a performance hit here. Also why asp.net team chose this route to instantiate the HttpApplication and hook the event handlers instead of a more obvious virtual-override way. This is something which I want to investigate now.

Answer (score 2):

All of the events of the [`HttpApplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) class can have a handler in the global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "automatically stub" the event handlers? Like typing the "override" and getting Intellisense telling what event handlers are available? Afraid that's not there...

Here is a link showing what's avaialble, though:

- [mha.dk](http://www.mha.dk/post/Globalasax-file---events.aspx)

Can't seem to find any definitive, complete listing anywhere, though :-(

Marc

Comment: Right...as in override, or on the Properties tab, one can usually select the event button to see and auto-wire up the delegates to the event by double-clicking. Something like that or an intellisense option.

There are lists everywhere describing what methods can be hooked up. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

HttpApplication.Init method is called after all of the module objects have been created and each of their Init methods has been called, which presents the perfect opportunity to set up event handlers, initialize a HttpModule?s instance variables, and to wireup event handlers to the hosting HttpApplication.

method name in asax Class is the concatenation of the value of the name attribute used to register the module in the Web.config file, an underscore, and
the name of the event.